# keep the selected Row highlighted after data refreshes in wpf datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm currently working on the rightFax app and i want to keep the selected row highlighted even after data refreshes, the grid is refreshing the data every minute and when does it looses the highlighted row. is there any way that i can keep the highlighted row?

please help me Thanks

```
 <Grid>
    <Toolkit:BusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}">
        <Grid>
            <DataGrid x:Name="dg_Faxes"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" MinHeight="100" MinWidth="100" Margin="5" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFax}"
              SelectionUnit="FullRow"  CanUserAddRows="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Faxes}"
              GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Sorting="dg_Faxes_Sorting" 
              HeadersVisibility="Column" SelectedValuePath="{Binding Path=Handle}">
            <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu IsOpen="{Binding IsContextOpened}">
                    <MenuItem Header="View Fax Image" Command="{Binding ViewFaxCommand}"></MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="Submit For Process" Command="{Binding SubmitFaxCommand}"></MenuItem>
                    <!--<MenuItem Header="Clear Comments" Command="{Binding ClearCommentsCommand}"></MenuItem>-->
                </ContextMenu>
            </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date/Time" MinWidth="100" CanUserSort="True" SortMemberPath="FaxRecordDateTime" 
                                Binding="{Binding Path=FaxRecordDateTime, StringFormat={}\{0:MMM dd\,\ yyyy hh:mm:ss tt\}}" IsReadOnly="True" >
                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <!--<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=FaxFilename}" Header="Name" CanUserSort="True" SortMemberPath="FaxFilename">
                </DataGridTextColumn>-->
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Pages" CanUserSort="True" SortMemberPath="TotalPages"
                                Binding="{Binding Path=TotalPages}" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserSort="True" SortMemberPath="IsPrinted" IsReadOnly="True" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Width="25" x:Name="IMG">
                                <Image.Source>
                                    <BitmapImage DecodePixelWidth="25" 
                                                 UriSource="../Icons/printer.png"></BitmapImage>
                                </Image.Source>
                                <Image.ToolTip>
                                    <ToolTip>
                                        <StackPanel>
                                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">Is Printed Column</TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock>Indicates Where A Document Has Been Printed</TextBlock>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </ToolTip>
                                </Image.ToolTip>
                            </Image>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Width="20" x:Name="IMG">
                                <Image.Source>
                                    <BitmapImage DecodePixelWidth="20" 
                                                 UriSource="../Icons/printer.png"></BitmapImage>
                                </Image.Source>
                            </Image>
                            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsPrinted}" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" TargetName="IMG"></Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserSort="True" SortMemberPath="IsViewed" IsReadOnly="True">                        
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>                            
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Width="25" x:Name="IMG">
                                <Image.Source>
                                    <BitmapImage DecodePixelWidth="25" 
                                                 UriSource="../Icons/eyeIcon.png"></BitmapImage>
                                </Image.Source>
                                <Image.ToolTip>
                                    <ToolTip>
                                        <StackPanel>
                                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">Is Viewed Column</TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock>Indicates Where A Document Has Been Viewed</TextBlock>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </ToolTip>
                                </Image.ToolTip>
                            </Image>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Width="20" x:Name="IMG">
                                <Image.Source>
                                    <BitmapImage DecodePixelWidth="20" 
                                                 UriSource="../Icons/eyeIcon.png"></BitmapImage>
                                </Image.Source>
                            </Image>
                            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsViewed}" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" TargetName="IMG"></Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                        
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <!--<DataGridTextColumn Header="IsPrinted" CanUserSort="True" SortMemberPath="IsPrinted"
                                Binding="{Binding Path=IsPrinted}" IsReadOnly="True" >
                </DataGridTextColumn>-->
                <!--<DataGridTextColumn Header="IsDeleted" CanUserSort="True" SortMemberPath="IsDeleted"
                                Binding="{Binding Path=IsDeleted}" IsReadOnly="True" >
                </DataGridTextColumn>-->
                <!--<DataGridTextColumn Header="IsApproved" CanUserSort="True" SortMemberPath="IsApproved"
                                Binding="{Binding Path=IsApproved}" IsReadOnly="True" >
                </DataGridTextColumn>-->
                <!--<DataGridTextColumn Header="IsViewed" CanUserSort="True" SortMemberPath="IsViewed"
                                Binding="{Binding Path=IsViewed}" IsReadOnly="True" >
                </DataGridTextColumn>-->
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Comments" CanUserSort="True" SortMemberPath="UserComments"
                                Binding="{Binding Path=UserComments}" IsReadOnly="True" >
                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <!--<DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" CanUserSort="True" SortMemberPath="StatusDescription"
                                Binding="{Binding Path=StatusDescription}" IsReadOnly="True" >
                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>-->
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status" CanUserSort="True" SortMemberPath="StatusDescription" IsReadOnly="True" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Width="20" x:Name="IMG" Source="../Icons/Red.png"></Image>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=StatusDescription}" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>                                
                            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=StatusDescription}" Value="OK">
                                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="../Icons/Green.png" TargetName="IMG"></Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
            <Toolkit:ChildWindow Caption="{Binding ChildName}" IsModal="True" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                         WindowState="{Binding ChildState}" MinWidth="300" WindowStartupLocation="Center">
            <Grid>
                <ContentControl
                        prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static Constants:RegionNames.FaxListChildRegion}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                            VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
            </Grid>
            </Toolkit:ChildWindow>
        </Grid>
    </Toolkit:BusyIndicator>
</Grid>
```

and code behind

public partial class FaxListsView : UserControl, IFaxListsView
    {
        private ListSortDirection lastSortDirection;
        private string lastSortMemberPath;
        public FaxListsView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

```
    }

    public IViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return (IViewModel)this.DataContext;
        }

        set
        {
            this.DataContext = value;
        }
    }

    private void dg_Faxes_Sorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
    {
        ((IFaxListsViewModel)this.DataContext).Sorted = true;
        if (e.Column.SortDirection != null && e.Column.SortDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
            ((IFaxListsViewModel)this.DataContext).SortDirection = "Descending";
        else
            ((IFaxListsViewModel)this.DataContext).SortDirection = "Ascending";

        ((IFaxListsViewModel)this.DataContext).SortColumnIndex = e.Column.DisplayIndex;


    }
    public void SortDataGrid(int columnIndex = 0, ListSortDirection sortDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending)
    {

        lastSortDirection = sortDirection;

        var column = dg_Faxes.Columns[columnIndex];

        dg_Faxes.Items.SortDescriptions.Clear();

        dg_Faxes.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(column.SortMemberPath, sortDirection));

        foreach (var col in dg_Faxes.Columns)
        {
            col.SortDirection = null;
        }

        column.SortDirection = sortDirection;

        dg_Faxes.Items.Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried keeping track of a key indicator of what was selected, and reselecting it (should it still be available) after the refresh?

Comment: you could also try to bind the IsSelected property of the row to a property on your data. This should keep the row selected after reloading.

Comment: how can i bind the IsSelected property ?

Comment: In your Datagrid Row Style try something like this: `<Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Selected}" />` And create a Selected property on your data